# Django-rss-plugin not working with internal RSS relative url

Tags: python, django, rss, atom-feed

I am having trouble using the internal RSS relative url in Django RSS plugin.
I am using this plugin [here](https://github.com/guangwenz/django-rss-plugin) to display feeds on my Django cms site.
This is only a problem when the feeds I am using uses internal RSS relative url
e.g using local server my website is at `http://127.0.0.1` and the feeds are accessed at `http://127.0.0.1/rss`. This never works. Also when the website is at `http://www.example.com` and the feeds at `http://www.example.com/rss` does not work!
But if the website is at `http://127.0.0.1`  and feeds at a different server like `http://www.example.com/rss` this works well. Also using the website at `http://www.example.com/rss` to access feeds at `http://127.0.0.1/rss` works well

I expect it to work when the feeds use internal RSS relative url as well as when the feed uses external RSS url

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://127.0.0.1/blog/rss for accessing the feeds.

Comment: No this did not work, but I have no such a URL in my `urls.py` file, where is the blog coming from?

Comment: Try adding port number as well in feeds URL on which server is running

Comment: Anyone who knows how to fix this?